# How to change values across multiple columns using a value conversion dataframe in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have an odd dataset of ~ 50 rows x 200 columns and I would like to re-code the values (strings) in certain columns using another dataframe encoding the conversion from old names to new names. I would like to do this in base R or dplyr, ideally using dplyr/ the tidyverse.

There are about 70 unique values to switch so coding each change individually would be too long (e.g. a simple str_replace), and there are about 70 columns containing the values I want changed so impractical to code anything specifying one named column at a time.

The columns containing values I want changed occur every third column excluding the first indexing column, and those values do not occur anywhere else in the dataframe. So a mutate_all type solution looking up any string across the dataframe that matches the old names in the conversion dataframe and replaces them with their new names would work. Note there is some data missingness.

Example data:

```
library("tidyverse")

# main dataset
col1 <- c("set1", "set2", "set3", "set4", "set5", "set6")
name_1 <- c("A", "D", "B", "A", "C", "A")
colour_1 <- c("red", "cyan", "red", "blue", "red", "blue")
shade_1 <- c("dark", "dark", "light", "light", "light", "light")
name_2 <- c("", "C", "D", "D", "", "A")
colour_2 <- c("", "red", "yellow", "blue", "", "purple")
shade_2 <- c("", "dark", "light", "dark", "", "light")
df_main <- data.frame(col1,name_1,colour_1,shade_1,name_2,colour_2,shade_2)

# The name_1 and name_2 columns are the ones I want changed, based on a conversion dataframe

# conversion dataframe
names_old <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
names_new <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
df_conversion <- data.frame(names_old,names_new)

# I want to base the switching from old names to new names in the main database using df_conversion

# Desired output
name_1_alt <- c("1", "4", "2", "1", "3", "1")
name_2_alt <- c("", "3", "4", "4", "", "1")
df_main_alt <- data.frame(col1,name_1_alt,colour_1,shade_1,name_2_alt,colour_2,shade_2)
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a named vector to match and change the values

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tibble)
df_main_alt1 <- df_main %>%
        mutate(across(starts_with('name'), ~ deframe(df_conversion)[.]))
df_main_alt1
#   col1 name_1 colour_1 shade_1 name_2 colour_2 shade_2
#1 set1      1      red    dark   <NA>                 
#2 set2      4     cyan    dark      3      red    dark
#3 set3      2      red   light      4   yellow   light
#4 set4      1     blue   light      4     blue    dark
#5 set5      3      red   light   <NA>                 
#6 set6      1     blue   light      1   purple   light
```

If we have a version of `dplyr` < 1.0.0, use `mutate_at`

```
df_main_alt1 <- df_main %>%
            mutate_at(vars(starts_with('name')), ~ 
                  deframe(df_conversion)[.])
```

Or may be use `recode`

```
df_main %>%
         mutate_at(vars(starts_with('name')), ~ 
             dplyr::recode(., !!! deframe(df_conversion)))
# col1 name_1 colour_1 shade_1 name_2 colour_2 shade_2
#1 set1      1      red    dark                        
#2 set2      4     cyan    dark      3      red    dark
#3 set3      2      red   light      4   yellow   light
#4 set4      1     blue   light      4     blue    dark
#5 set5      3      red   light                        
#6 set6      1     blue   light      1   purple   light
```

Comment: What version of R/dplyr does this need? I got an error "could not find function "across"".

Comment: @WillHamiltoni used `1.0.0`.  If your version is less than that, use `mutate_at`.  updated thepost

Comment: @WillHamilton is there any other changes you needed in the function

Comment: Problem - blank cells are replaced by the first value of the vector. I tried changing blank cells to NA with the line: df_main <- df_main %>% mutate_all(na_if,""). But for my dataset that changed the conversion so the names stopped corresponding to the correct values.

Comment: @WillHamilton is it based on the same input data?  I couldn't reproduce the issue with that example though

Comment: @WillHamilton I updated with the answer I got.  Can you please crosscheck with your results

Comment: I'm using the version with  dplyr <1.0.0/ mutate_at (working off a work computer that I can't easily install updates on). The rows with blank values are given '1' rather than blank or NA in the output

Comment: @WillHamilton ok, then it must be an issue with the dplyr version because both the `mutate_at` and `mutate(across` are giving me the same output

Comment: @WillHamilton can you try with `recode` (I updated now)

Comment: When I get home I'll try on my own laptop with mutate_across

Comment: @WillHamilton the `recode` is pretty old function.  So, it should work on your version

Comment: With the recode version I get, "Error: Arguments 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 must be named, not unnamed".

Comment: @WillHamilton okay, so may be your version is very old

Comment: the mutate(across version works fine on my laptop using R v 4.0.2, tibble_3.0.3 and dplyr_1.0.1, so it was just an issue with an old version of R before. Thanks for the help.